# What is the shortest regex for the month of January in a handful of the world's languages?

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

What is the shortest regular expression equivilant to the following?

```
ENERO|GENER|GENNAIO|IANUARI|IANUARII|IONAWR|JAANUARIL|JANAIRU|JANAR|JANNEWARIS|JANUAR|JANUARI|JANUARIE|JANUARO|JANUARY|JANUWALE|JANVIER|JANVYE|JENUWARI
```

The shortest regex, in bytes, wins.

If you are worried about what flavor of regex we are using, then be the first one to edit my question, and you can have a link to a description of the specific regex flavor of your choice. Please choose a mainstream regex flavor, nothing too esoteric. `*` should mean `zero or more`. `+` should be `one or more` and so on and so forth.

Comment: That way of choosing a regex flavor seems really weird; why not just allow all regex flavors? Answers could then just specify in the header which flavor they're using (this also makes the competition more interesting, since people have a broader range of features available)

Comment: What do you mean by "handful"?

Comment: @UndoneStudios they mean the ones in the question

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms We have to hold the regex flavor constant, otherwise you could invent your own flavor of regex which is simply `J`. Given that `J` is one character, you would probably win the competition.

Comment: @UndoneStudios The title of the question is shorter than the body of the question. The names for the month of January will not all fit inside of a single question title.  `ENERO|GENER|GENNAIO|IANUARI|IANUARII|IONAWR|JAANUARIL|JANAIRU|JANAR|JANNEWARIS|JANUAR|JANUARI|JANUARIE|JANUARO|JANUARY|JANUWALE|JANVIER|JANVYE|JENUWARI`

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon We already have rules that take care of this problem. Scoring is per-language here; an answer in PCRE doesn't compete with one in g/re/p regex, only other PCRE answers. So a single-byte answer in a custom flavor only wins for that flavor, and is thus pointless.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon That's already a standard forbidden loophole: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/58624

Answer (score 6):

#### Python `re` module, 104 <s>110</s> bytes

-6 based on Neil's comment

```
JENUWARI|JA(N(VYE|VIER|UWALE|UAR(IE?|Y|O)?|NEWARIS|AIRU|AR)|ANUARIL)|IONAWR|IANUARII?|GEN(NAIO|ER)|ENERO
```

Comment: `|AIRU|AR)|` is a byte shorter than `|A(IRU|R))|`. (I think the same idea applies in a few other places as well.) Similarly, `|Y|O` is a byte shorter than `|[YO]`.

Answer (score 4):

## 104 bytes

```
ENERO|GEN(ER|NAIO)|IANUARII?|IONAWR|JAANUARIL|JAN(AIRU|AR|NEWARIS|UAR(IE?|O|Y)?|UWALE|VIER|VYE)|JENUWARI
```

Should work with <s>any</s> most<sup>†</sup> regex styles, since I only use `|?()`, but below is a TIO for Java:

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZVHRTsIwFH3nK2721AaFd3wgjalmBrtkEwgxPlSYMhwbWQuGePfts3MbtuOpveee23t6zk6e5O1u81WtU6kUPMsk@xkAHI7vabIGpaU2xylPNrA3LRLpIsk@X98krVkAH3lBTrIAHSt9L1U8yeJv6EgNBWA8hpfiqLfnSQt4XPAw8G668rGunVIw3@r7TMxZ6F8BNhIItrTeeGINZWZD5tVw7gLOiBB8aWYiB5v3OK6SFuB9JOgDKxdYspk7s/C5u2exsgm8HrEWG08fZKr@Le25GfS@eSWZ@65ZljUlbRvRWel4P8qPenQwkeo0I13QQ28C3rCrRnup19tYkaqJFo0GwkOsY6TYpTXFJiW8hGNugtSbkRlyYz6aDvH5FANc0Sn@OYW1O2gcoXhxomo0Unpn1JaDsvoF)

The last portion of the regex above could be one of these three for the same byte count:

- `JAANUARIL|JAN(AIRU|AR|NEWARIS|UAR(IE?|O|Y)?|UWALE|VIER|VYE)|JENUWARI` (the one used above)
- `JA(ANUARIL|N(AIRU|AR|NEWARIS|UAR(IE?|O|Y)?|UWALE|VIER|VYE))|JENUWARI` (`JA` combined for suffix of two options)
- `J(AANUARIL|AN(AIRU|AR|NEWARIS|UAR(IE?|O|Y)?|UWALE|VIER|VYE)|ENUWARI)` (`J` combined for suffix of three options)

Very curious if <104 bytes is even possible at this point.

†: Apparently not all. Thanks for the info *@ikkachu*.

Comment: not _any_ regex style: standard POSIX _basic_ REs (as used by e.g. `sed` and `grep` without the `-E` options) require  `\(`/`\)` for grouping, don't have `?` (but `\{0,1\}` does the same) and have _no syntax for alternation at all_.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah ok, that's good to know. I don't know too much about all the different regex flavors I must admit. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

## 110 bytes

```
J(A(N(U(AR([OY]|IE?)?|WALE)|V(IER|YE)|A(IRU|R)|NEWARIS)|ANUARIL)|ENUWARI)|I(ANUARI?I|ONAWR)|GEN(NAIO|ER)|ENERO
```

Which may be more easily read with designified whitespace like this:

```
J(
    A(
        N(
            U(
                AR(
                    [OY]
                   | IE?
                )?
              | WALE
            )
            | V(IER | YE)
            | A(IRU | R)
            | NEWARIS
        )
        | ANUARIL
    )
  | ENUWARI
)
| I(ANUARI?I | ONAWR)
| GEN(NAIO   | ER)
| ENERO
```

This pattern works both in engines guaranteed to select the leftmost valid alternative in an `A|B|C` set, as well as in engines guaranteed to choose the longest valid alternative overall from that set.

Because of its alternation of literal strings, this pattern runs faster in engines with the [Aho–Corasick trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) optimization than in those lacking that feature.

Comment: I'm guessing that you could make the same savings as I suggested for @RootToo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## 104 bytes

```
ENERO|GEN(NAIO|ER)|IANUARII?|IONAWR|JA(ANUARIL|N(AIRU|AR|NEWARIS|UAR(IE?|O|Y|)|UWALE|VIER|VYE))|JENUWARI
```

Or, formatted more nicely (with insignificant whitespace):

```
ENERO |
GEN(
    NAIO |
    ER
) |
IANUARI I? |
IONAWR |
JA(
    ANUARIL |
    N(
        AIRU |
        AR |
        NEWARIS |
        UAR(
            I E? |
            O |
            Y |
            [the empty string]
        ) |
        UWALE |
        VIER |
        VYE
    )
) |
JENUWARI
```

Answer (score 0):

## 104 bytes

```
ENERO|GEN(ER|NAIO)|IANUARII?|IONAWR|JA(ANUARIL|N(UWALE|VIER|VYE|UAR(IE?|O|Y)?|NEWARIS|AIRU|AR))|JENUWARI
```

<sup>Spent way too long trying to find a shorter solution and am convinced it doesn't exist.</sup>

Comment: Note that this is exactly the same as Starwort’s solution, just reordered slightly

Comment: @noodleman indeed, I didn't realize until after I posted and since I spent quite a bit I didn't want to delete it.